# Duplicating a video in gstreamer to be passed back up the pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

I have been trying to make a pipeline that has both a videomixer then a tee, in that order, and i am trying to loop the video from the tee back round to the mixer. i was hoping this would be like a "b stop" on cameras, but progressively over the video, so as you record the video layers over itself, creating like a blur, in the sort of way you see in pictures of the stars with trails because of longer exposures, accumulating as the video goes on.

My problem is that I can not convince `tee.link(mixer)` to work, and I do not know whether I am doing something wrong or that I cannot pass a stream back along the pipeline. If anyone knows why it isn't working, or can suggest a better method, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needed a `queue` element.......